# How to add multiplelines answer in WebChat channel

Tags: c#, botframework

Is it possible to allow the user to accept multiple line answers using WebChat channel?

Currently, when typing enter, the bot just moves to the next question, when using WebChat channel.

I tried different variations of enter: Shift enter, alt enter, enter etc, all do not work.

Is that supported in WebChat?

Comment: Bot replies on last command. I think this is impossible for now.

Comment: I just want the message itself to include newlines. It doesn't have to be sent in seperate messages. I'm looking for some magic SHIFT+ENTER coombination that would let the user add newlines in his messages.

Answer (score 0):

It's a Textbox and not a text area. TextBox does not allows multiple line.

If it was using a textarea, it would be possible.